# Get Process Address by searching the string in the memory

Tags: vb.net, string, memory

im trying to get the Process Address by searching the string of it. They way it works in Cheat Engine. I want to search for a string and it returns with a Address. I have no Idea how im suppose to do that and i wasnt able to find any helpful tutorials. I already have a script which can read/write Data but not search for it.

Comment: Where is the Data located, a datatbase, a textfile, etc? Have you tried anything, if so can you post your code?

Comment: Data is located in the program itself. no, because i dont know how to do this.